# Adding dictionary to array in plist file

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, swift3

I have been trying to add a dictionary to my `plist` file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>id</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>inlat</key>
    <real>49.7930491922698</real>
    <key>inlong</key>
    <real>9.92656307493522</real>
    <key>titel</key>
    <string>Würzburg</string>
    <key>flussname</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>ort</key>
    <string>Würzburg</string>
    <key>land</key>
    <string>Deutschland</string>
    <key>poiart</key>
    <string>Playspot</string>
    <key>charakter</key>
    <string>Welle</string>
    <key>mindestpegel</key>
    <string>-</string>
    <key>besonderheiten</key>
    <string>Hochwasserspot</string>
    <key>pegellink</key>
    <string>www.xxx.html</string>
    <key>beschreibungslink</key>
    <string>www.xxx.html</string>
    <key>fotolink</key>
    <string>www.xxx.html</string>
    <key>outlat</key>
    <real>48.7930491922698</real>
    <key>outlong</key>
    <real>8.92656307493522</real>
   </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

I have been searching at google for two months and tried to save this data in my plist file in a function you see below.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


var Titel = "Titel"

var Flussname = "Flussname"

var Ort = "Ort"

var Land = "Land"

var POIart = "POIart"

var Charakter = "Charakter"

var Mindestpegel = "Mindestpegel"

var Besonderheiten = "Besonderheiten"

var Pegellink = "Pegellink"

var Beschreibungslink = "Beschreibungslink"

var Fotolink = "Fotolink"

var Latitude = 1.123456

var Longitude = 1.123456




let TitelKey = "titel"

let FlussnameKey = "flussname"

let OrtKey = "ort"

let LandKey = "land"

let POIartKey = "poiart"

let CharakterKey = "charakter"

let MindestpegelKey = "mindestpegel"

let BesonderheitenKey = "besonderheiten"

let PegellinkKey = "pegellink"

let BeschreibungslinkKey = "beschreibungslink"

let FotolinkKey = "fotolink"

let LatitudeKey = "lat"

let LongitudeKey = "long"








@IBOutlet weak var I: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var II: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var III: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var IV: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var V: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var VI: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var VII: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var VIII: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var IX: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var X: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var XI: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var XII: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var XIII: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    I.text = Titel
    II.text = Flussname
    III.text = Ort
    IV.text = Land
    V.text = POIart
    VI.text = Charakter
    VII.text = Mindestpegel
    VIII.text = Besonderheiten
    IX.text = Pegellink
    X.text = Beschreibungslink
    XI.text = Fotolink
}

@IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {


    self.saveData()
}

func saveData () {

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) [0] as String
    let documentsDirectory = paths.appending("/Favoriten.plist")
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: documentsDirectory)
    {
        // Default plist name is Info. Just using ClassA
        let bundle = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Favoriten", ofType: "plist")
        try! fileManager.copyItem(atPath: bundle!, toPath: documentsDirectory)
    }


    let data = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: documentsDirectory)

    //saving values
    data?.setObject(Titel, forKey: TitelKey as NSCopying)
    data?.setObject(Flussname, forKey: FlussnameKey as NSCopying)
    data?.setObject(Ort, forKey: OrtKey as NSCopying)
    data?.setObject(Land, forKey: LandKey as NSCopying)
    data?.setObject(POIart, forKey: POIartKey as NSCopying)
    data?.setObject(Charakter, forKey: CharakterKey as NSCopying)
    data?.setObject(Mindestpegel, forKey: MindestpegelKey as NSCopying)
    data?.setObject(Besonderheiten, forKey: BesonderheitenKey as NSCopying)
    data?.setObject(Pegellink, forKey: PegellinkKey as NSCopying)
    data?.setObject(Beschreibungslink, forKey: BeschreibungslinkKey as NSCopying)
    data?.setObject(Fotolink, forKey: FotolinkKey as NSCopying)
    data?.setObject(Latitude, forKey: LatitudeKey as NSCopying)
    data?.setObject(Longitude, forKey: LongitudeKey as NSCopying)



    //writing to .plist
    data?.write(toFile: documentsDirectory, atomically: true)

    print(data)
}
```

Please can you give me an example or a tip where I might find a tutorial, as I am really lost.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

plists only save a very small number of data types. Try casting both your key and value to `NSString`s. Also protect your read of the dictionary with a guard statement and print an error if it fails:

```
guard let data = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: documentsDirectory) else {
  print(Error reading data from file \(documentsDirectory)")
  return
}

data[TitelKey as NSString] = Titel as NSString
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this for example:

```
// Create the new dictionary that will be inserted into the plist.
NSMutableDictionary *nameDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[nameDictionary setValue:@"FirstName LastName" forKey:@"fullName"];
[nameDictionary setValue:@"123 North Rd" forKey:@"address"];

// Open the plist from the filesystem.
NSMutableArray *plist = [NSMutableArray      arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/file.plist"];
if (plist == nil) plist = [NSMutableArray array];
[plist addObject:nameDictionary];
[plist writeToFile:@"/path/to/file.plist" atomically:YES];
```

Comment: The OP's question uses Swift. Your answer is Objective-C. Regardless, you should not use `setValue:forKey:` That is a KVO method. You should use `setObject:forKey:`